# sed remove all lines containing the word password.But don't keep the empty line

Tags: regex, linux, sed

My file has lines

```
Database Name:Mydb
DatabaseServer:DbServer
Password:Example
Username:User1

Database Name:Mydb1
DatabaseServer:DbServer1
Password:Example1
Username:User11
```

I used sed -i "s/password.*//gI" file but that is leaving an empty line(in place of password.*) which i don't want.

Desired result:

```
Database Name:Mydb
DatabaseServer:DbServer
Username:User1

Database Name:Mydb1
DatabaseServer:DbServer1
Username:User11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give this a try:

```
sed -i '/Password:/d' file
```

Comment: It actually not just Password: . Some times it also has password=, password$. All kind of symbols. I used sed -i '/Password:/d' file which is working but its not removing case-insensitive ones. I used sed -i '/Password:/dI' file and its throwing "unsupported command I" error.

Comment: @NarenNidamanuri then you try `/^[Pp]assword/d` You got error msg because you gave wrong sed command.

Comment: Yes. '/[Pp][Aa][Ss][Ss][Ww][Oo][Rr][Dd].*/d' also worked perfectly. Thanks. Now I am conflicted which answer to mark as correct. I requested a sed answer. So marked it correct.

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1st: `grep` here to help.

```
grep -v '^Password'  Input_file
```

In case you need to save into same Input_file then you could following.

```
grep -v '^Password'  Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** Using `awk`.

```
awk '!/^Password/' Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```

Comment: Perfect. Used grep -iv ".*password.*"  file. And I am all good. But kind of feel stupid though for not even thinking of grep.

Comment: @NarenNidamanuri, cool(not an issue), glad to help you. Cheers happy learning. Also after sometime you could select any of the answers as correct answer which helped you too.

Comment: DOWN VOTER, not fair why down vote without giving reason :(

Comment: Wait. What? Where did I down-vote? I up-voted both your answers(kent's and yours). @RavinderSingh13

Comment: @Naren, it was NOT addressed to you, it was addressed to down voter.